# VSC Terminal - GNU Screen number of lines in the history

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I use VSC and "screens" in the Terminal to watch the processes on the server (Node) (https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)
Earlier I was able to see many rows in the Terminal, also I was able to search in the console.log() history.
Beacause of an update on the server, the Screen in the Terminal shows only a few rows now (the number of rows that fit on the terminal height only) and the search doesn't work for the whole history.
I set the option "terminal.integrated.scrollback" to 10000, but this doesn't help, because the number of rows depends from the Screen settings.
Can you help me understand what setting should be changed on the server to get many rows of the history in the Screen-> terminal?
(Tried: defscrollback 10000 in the ~/screenrc - doesn't help!).
Thanks.

Comment: When using GNU screen (and tmux, etc.), that has its own [search](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Searching) feature (VSC won't know about that).

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I use this search tool. But it is less useful than VSC Terminal Search feature. Because of this I d like to disable the Screen mode to show as many rows as fit into the Terminal window. Earlier I seen many rows and used the Terminal Search tool, now I see several rows that fit into Terminal window and the seach working for these rows only. I m trying to disable this mode.